# .change() get :selected text value

Tags: jquery, selected

I'm trying to run the following code

```
$("select#shipping_rates_drop").change(function(){
            var selectedText = $(this + "option:selected").text();
            var ship = thisvalue.split("£");
            var subtotal = $("ul#deliveryList").attr("class");
            var ship = ship[1];
            var totalcost = parseFloat(subtotal)+parseFloat(ship);
            $(".wrap.form-section h1 span").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>Total </small> £"+totalcost);
            $("input[name=itemamt]").val(subtotal);
            $("input[name=shippingamt]").val(ship);
            checklistCheck1();
        });
```

I want to get the text from the selected value on change. ex. UPS Worldwide Express - £89.57
then the code splits the value to get me the actual number of cost.

But console.log throws up the following

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object
>   HTMLSelectElement]option:selected

in jquery.min.js (line 2)

So im assuming I've done something wrong here and hoping someone could help out

Comment: The beginning of the code looks wrong but I guess that's just a copy/paste issue right?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

the line should be

```
var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
var thisvalue = $(this + "option:selected").text();
```

to

```
var thisvalue = $("select#shipping_rates_drop option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 6):

**Selected text value :**

```
$('#selectBoxId').on('change',function(){
   var optionsText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
   alert(optionsText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<select onchange="changeSelect($event)">
    <option [value]="valor">Texto</option>
</select>
```

```js
changeSelect(e: any) {
    var indexSel = e.target.selectedIndex;
    var label = e.srcElement[indexSel].label;console.log(label);
}
```